# Non-static method on get() called method

Tags: php, laravel, error-handling

i got this error

Non-static method Illuminate\Http\Request::get() should not be called statically

and this is my code

```
tanaman = tanaman::where('nama_tanaman', '=', Request::get('nama_tanaman'))->first();
    if ($tanaman === null) {
```

any solution ?

Comment: When you get an error message, always start by googling it. There are _many_ questions/answers about it all over.

Answer (score 0):

The error message is due to the call not going through the Request facade.

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class YourController extends Controller {
    public function YourMethodName(Request $request) {
        tanaman = tanaman::where('nama_tanaman', $request->nama_tanaman)->first();
    }
}
```

Or you can call request facade as below:

```
class MyController() {
    protected $request;
    public function __construct(\Illuminate\Http\Request $request) {
        $this->request = $request;
    }

    public function myFunc() {
        $input = $this->request->all();
    }
}
```